# имелся, what conjugation is this?

Tags: глаголы

I have been trying to figure out what conjugation "имелся" is; as far as I understand it is some form of "иметь".  I have consulted various conjugation charts and none of them have this word.  The only result I have gotten is by putting it into google translate, which said it was a past tense "I had," but I am not sure how accurate this is.  Thank you.

Comment: Luisa, if you go here http://rifmovnik.ru/find.htm, click on "рифмы" next to the search field and select "словоформы," you can enter any form of any word and it will take you to the headword and show you the entire conjugation (or declension of nouns and adjectives).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really past tense of иметь,rather иметься, masculine, and it means *there was*, for example :There was a house in the picture. It isn't *I had*, it's impersonal,a bit bookish and old-fashioned  and rarely used nowadays. We say был instead. They say I should have mentioned 1 conjugation.

Comment: i understand now.  the example comes from a book i am translating for practice which takes place in the 1880s, so that explains why it is old fashioned perhaps.  thank you.

Comment: You should have given the sentence. It would have been easier to explain the meaning.

Comment: i will keep that in mind for the future, thank you.  your answer works for the sentence in this case and i able to understand it.

Comment: Good luck in your studies.

Comment: Why not answer the OP question directly and say it is a 1st conjugation verb? _Luisa, it is a 1st (I) conjugation verb!_

Comment: You're welcome to present your own answer, I can delete mine.